# How can I get a reference of a prefab asset from the code in it self?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path, reference, prefab

So let's say I have this prefab asset, "P" and have this code attached to it.

```
public GameObject selfReference;

[ContextMenu("GetReference")]
public void GetReference()
{
    selfReference = gameObject;
}
```

Note that:
the 'reference finding' process is trigger by ContextMenu so **it is done in Edit Mode**, not Play Mode;
and **all of this is happening in the prefab asset "P" itself**, not some random instance of it placed in the scene.

---

So I tried

```
selfReference = PrefabUtility.GetNearestPrefabInstanceRoot(gameObject);
```

but it didn't work so tried to load it via path:

```
string _path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(gameObject);
```

but it returns only blank string.

Any help plz?

Comment: I don't understand the question ... this shouldn't be any problem on a prefab ...

Comment: My bad sorry about that. Problem's solved. I didn't mention that I was using GetReference method in OnAfterDeserialization, and that was the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume -  since it works for me ;)

[image]

that your question is rather related to this change not being saved correctly and not being handled for undo/redo.

You should probably do e.g.

```
public GameObject selfReference;

[ContextMenu(nameof(GetReference))]
public void GetReference()
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    if(!Application.isPlaying)
    {
        UnityEditor.Undo.RecordObject(this, "fetched self-reference");

        if (UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.IsPartOfAnyPrefab(this))
        {
            UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications(this);
        }
    }
#endif

    selfReference = gameObject;
}
```

besides that of course it appears a bit redundant to me to have a field for something that is exposed via the property anyway ;)

Comment: First of all, HUGE thanks for such a detailed and kind answer. Thanks to you I was able to solve my problem though as it turns out my question itself was at the wrong point. The problem had nothing to do with prefab but was about ISerializationCallBackReceiver. I didn't mention about it to shorten the question but what I actually was doing was running "GetReference" method not by ContextMenu, but in OnAfterDeserialize. And the problem was that it is not allowed to use "gameObject" keyword in OnAfterDeserialize. I simply moved the line of code to OnBeforeSerialize and everything worked fine.

Comment: Again, sorry for misguided question but I was able to find the actual problem only because I tried your solution. Thanks!